# Can "Dylib Hijacking" happen on iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm told that [Dylib Hijacking](https://www.virusbulletin.com/virusbulletin/2015/03/dylib-hijacking-os-x) vulnerability exists on Mac applications.

And he told me that, in theory, it can also happen on iOS apps.
I googled a lot for any discussion about it, but nothing was found about iOS apps.

Now I'm wondering if it really can happen on iOS apps. After some investigation, my understanding is that for this vulnerability to happen, the following conditions must be satisfied:

- The malicious library has to be found before the app can find the correct library
- Attackers have to have write permission to the folder
- Attackers have to launch the app after injecting the malicious library

In my iOS app case, all of the libraries are found in the 2nd ranked RPATH `@executable_path/Frameworks`, so attackers have to place the malicious library in the 1st ranked RPATH `/usr/lib/swift`.

- Is the folder `/usr/lib/swift` writable in iOS devices in general?
- If it requires a jailbrake, can’t we avoid this issue by forbidding those devices from using our app?

If you're aware of this vulnerability on iOS apps, that is totally helpful.